# Is it possible to configure an iOS device to remember credentials for a Wifi SSID but NOT auto-join it?

Tags: ios, wifi

I want to:

1. leave Wifi enabled on the device
2. Make iOS remember the password for SSID A (e.g. Private corporate network)
3. Make iOS never connect to SSID A silently

This allows the following flow:

4. Manually connect to SSID A from the Wifi menu
5. Upon disconnecting from SSID A, require step 4 prior to re-connecting to SSID A

Example: By default, upon entering the range of SSID A, using the iOS device continues to use either built in cellular or SSID B. After step 4 above and until the end of the day, the device will be on the network.

For now the workarounds are:

- Switch Wifi off when at work. Failure point: Forget to do it in the morning, leading to use of the network when not intending to. Further cons: consumes LTE bandwidth unnecessarily, and disables Wifi (which would disable e.g. tethering)
- Forget SSID A in the menu. Dealbreaking pain point: have to use a clipboard manager or other insecure tools or brain power to restore the password for SSID A when actually required to connect.

Comment: I'm pretty certain that jailbreaking allows for the installation of tools that can solve the problem, but I won't treat that as a valid answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it seems like my phone (i now have an iPhone X) now provides an 'Auto-Join' option for a wifi network.

So just switching this to off should in theory implement what I want (a saved network that will not get auto-joined).

Answer (score 1):

There's isn't a great solution but one possible workaround is to set SSID A to use a non routing static IP and just switch it back to DHCP whenever you actually want to use it. Just click the circled i to the right of the network name and click the Static toggle.

You'll need to enter a valid (but non functional) static IP and Subnet Mask (I tested with 10.1.1.1 and 255.0.0.0) or it won't keep the static IP setting. This let's you keep wifi on all the time and never enter your password again.

Comment: This is brilliant and I love it. Might actually start using this. The main thing is that I only very rarely do need to get my phone onto the particular network in question.

Comment: So does it just fail to route? Won't it introduce a delay with network connections? Or I guess the phone will attempt a connection every time it comes within range but will never be able to establish a connection, and it becomes effectively the same as not attempting to connect to it. My concern is that i'd like to avoid introducing the behavior as seen in [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/280566)

Comment: I wonder if it will suppress the ability to connect to SSID B when in SSID A's range though. I guess changing the network priority sort for SSID A to be the lowest will deal with that effectively as well!

Comment: I don't see a Wifi icon when doing this and I don't see any delay so I think because the connection isn't usable iOS appears to just ignore it. I don't specify a router so I'm essentially saying only use this as a local connection to access IP addresses that are directly accessible. It does connect to SSID A so you may have to manually select SSID B if they're both in range.